Why doesn't Minecraft for Android transfer to laptop(Windows 10)
I have Minecraft installed on my Android 13 tablet. I want to play Minecraft on my Windows 10 laptop. I figured it would work seamlessly because I am signed into my Microsoft account on my tablet, playing Minecraft using that Xbox account, and seeing updates on my Xbox account from my laptop. However, when I opened the Minecraft launcher on my laptop, I had to pay again for Minecraft for Windows 10(bedrock edition). When I did some research, I found out that the pocket edition is no longer a separate edition, and it is now bedrock edition, so I don't understand why I can't access it on my laptop.

While Minecraft on all platforms may be owned by Mojang/Microsoft, the stores used to buy and install the game aren't. Microsoft isn't going to let you play the game for free just because you bought it from Google (you said Android so I assume Google).
Take this analogy.
It's sort of like a "Premium Pass" at an arcade. If you get a "Premium Pass" at one arcade, it won't be accepted by an arcade owned by a different company for the sole reason being because they are both arcades.
